# Excel VBA insert records from database in correct order

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm trying to get records from a database and fill them into excel.
This is how I get the data and fill it (note: the query is simplified, I can't just `ORDER BY DESC`):

```
Sub FillPersons(ByRef connection As ADODB.connection)
    Dim recordSet As ADODB.recordSet
    Set recordSet = New ADODB.recordSet
    Dim sql As String

    sql = "SELECT TOP 2 Id FROM Persons"

    recordSet.activeconnection = connection 
    recordSet.Open sql

    Dim a As Variant

    If Not recordSet.EOF Then
        a = recordSet.GetRows
        a.Reverse (a)
        Sheet1.Cells(10, 2).Resize(UBound(a, 1) + 1, UBound(a, 2) + 1).Value = a
    End If

    'Sheet1.Range("B10").CopyFromRecordset recordSet

    recordSet.Close
    connection .Close
    Set connection = Nothing
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, the result looks like this:

<kbd>B10</kbd><kbd>B11</kbd>
<kbd>2</kbd>    <kbd>1</kbd>

instead of

<kbd>B10</kbd><kbd>B11</kbd>
<kbd>1</kbd>    <kbd>2</kbd>

I've tried to reverse `a` but unfortunately I can't get it to work.

Is there a trick to get the correct result?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's not enough data to ascertain a definite pattern, but I'm guessing it's in the right order, but in reverse?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to sort / reverse `a` instead of `recordSet`?

Use
`recordset.Sort = recordSet.Fields(1).Name & " ASC"`

More details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675783(v=vs.85).aspx